# Convert a dataset from space separated to tab separated

Tags: linux, bash, file

I have this dataset where each line has two space separated words. I want the space between the two words of each line to be converted to a tab. I'm learning bash scripting and I have no clue what to do. Can anyone help?
dataset eg-

> Confidence NN
>  in IN
>  the DT
>  pound NN
>  is VBZ

Comment: `tr ' ' '\t' < file > out.file`

Comment: would have accepted if it was an answer. anyway thanks it worked

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: You might want to [Take the Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to use Stack Overflow effectively. In the meantime, maybe [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com) or [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com) can help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` for that:

`sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/\t/g" <file>`

or like wrote anubhava in comments :

```
tr ' ' '\t' < file > out.file
```